# Lax-Friedrichs scheme stability necessary sufficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

We have the advection equation $q_t+aq_x = 0$ with constant velocity $a$ and the Lax-Friedrichs scheme

$Q_j^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(Q_{j-1}^n+Q_{j+1}^n)+\frac{ak}{2h}(Q_{j-1}^n-Q_{j+1}^n)$.

How to show that $|\frac{ak}{h}|\leq 1$ is necessary for stability and sufficient for stability in the discrete $L^1$ norm?

**Edit**:
The discrete $L^1$ norm is defined as

$\|Q^{n+1}\|_1 = h\sum\limits_j|Q_j^{n+1}|$.

So far I've noted the above as:

$\|Q^{n+1}\|_1=h\sum\limits_j\left|\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{ak}{h})Q_{j-1}^n + \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{ak}{h})Q_{j+1}^n\right|$

How should I take it from here?

Comment: @EditPiAf I've got my Bachelor in 2010 and now I'm self studying Numerics via an old script of a Prof from my old University. There he states, that $ak/h\leq 1$ is necessary and sufficient for stability of the LF scheme... I wanted to proof it by myself but I'm failing where to start. Neumann stability comes two lectures later, so I think, that it is done without Neumann.

Comment: @EditPiAf Edited the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Necessity:**

The stated condition is precisely the [CFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition) condition.

**Sufficiency:**

It appears that you have a couple of sign errors in your final expression. It should read

\begin{align}
\| Q^{n+1} \|_1 &= h \sum_j \left| \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{ak}{h} \right) Q^n_{j-1} + \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{ak}{h} \right) Q^n_{j+1} \right| \\
%
&\leq \frac{h}{2} \left[ \sum_j \left| \left( 1 + \frac{ak}{h} \right) Q_{j-1}^n \right| + \sum_j \left| \left( 1 - \frac{ak}{h} \right) Q_{j+1}^n \right| \right]
\end{align}

Now, suppose that $\left| \frac{ak}{h} \right| \leq 1$. Then it holds that
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{ak}{h} \right) \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \left( 1 + \frac{ak}{h} \right) \geq 0.
$$
Thus, these terms can be extracted from the absolute values to get

\begin{align}
\| Q^{n+1} \|_1 &\leq \frac{h}{2} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac{ak}{h} \right) \sum_j \left| Q_{j-1}^n \right| + \left( 1 - \frac{ak}{h} \right) \sum_j \left| Q_{j+1}^n \right| \right] \\
%
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac{ak}{h} \right) \| Q^n \|_1 + \left( 1 - \frac{ak}{h} \right) \| Q^n \|_1 \right] \\
%
&= \| Q^n \|_1.
\end{align}

The method is therefore stable.

Comment: thank you for your help!